# Spring boot run multiple instances of same profile in service

Tags: spring-boot

In Spring boot application, how run multiple instances of same profile on same server (OS)?

Comment: Just do it?  What's the problem with running your app twice using the same profile? Does your profile specify something that can't be used twice, like a particular port number to listen on or something like that? - ha.  Saw answer only after I posted this.  @Nesrin was all over it with my same thinking about the port.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To run multiple instances of same profile of service

- remove property from profile in yml (or properties) file -> server.port (this is in case of using remote configuration accessed through configuration server)
- on running the war (or jar) set the property of port and profile in command line as follows

> java -jar  -Dserver.port=**7012** -Dspring.profiles.active=production
> demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>
> java -jar  -Dserver.port=**7011**
> -Dspring.profiles.active=production demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Thanks, so what about to do the same from eclipse during development

Comment: same parameters are passed from  configurations:
1- go to run configurations
2- open argument tab
3- add the line :  -Dserver.port=7011 -Dspring.profiles.active=production

Comment: I don't think you have to remove the property from your profile.  A Java property should override what's in your profile, per [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: Yes @Steve , but if using configuration server in case of microservice architecture, it's better to remove, sometimes don't work well

Comment: @Nesrin - curious...why not? - I think I've done this without a problem

Comment: @Steve, I updated the previous comment with more clarification to the case faced me

Comment: @Nesrin - Did this guy mention a microservice architecture? There's a reason for the Spring hierarchy of property locations being what it is, and overriding properties at different levels makes good sense.  Why not have a meaningful default in your profile so you don't have to set a system property if you don't need to?  Cascading properties are an obvious win, by design.

Comment: You are right @Steve, I will update the answer for more clarification

Comment: @Steve you are totally right, even if we do have several profiles, for instance, a test and a production one and each one has its own port, if the test profile is active the port on it will override the port in the default profile, and as you said java properties will override all the defined properties in the configuration files,   Another remarque for Nesrin there is no need to activate the production profile property in the command line, if you do have only one profile it will be automatically the default one!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run multiple instances of your project in sts (spring tool suite) follow below steps

1. change server.port=0 (this makes application run on random port) in application.properties or yaml
2. open Boot bashboard, run instance once, it will start running on random port
3. right click that intance, click duplicate config, it will create new instance in boot dashboard
4. run new instance that will be started on new random port

you can create as many duplicate instance you want